# Как правильно сделать? PHP регистрация

Tags: php, form, if

Начал учить PHP. Возник вопрос.
Есть следующий код:

```
if ($_GET['page']=="post") {

// Приводим символы к хтмль и переводим в нижний регистр
$login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$login = strtolower($login);
$pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

if (empty($login)) {echo "Вы не заполнили поле логин";}
if (strlen($login) > 33) {echo "Логин длинее 32 символов, не допустим";}
if (empty($pass)) {echo "Поле пароль не может быть пустым";}
if (strlen($pass) > 65) {echo "Пароль должен содержать не более 64 символов";}
if (strlen($pass) < 5) {echo "Пароль должен содержать более 5 символов";}
}
```

Мне нужно, сделать следующиее. Если все проверки IF пройдены успешно, выполнить этот код:

```
//Выполнить если все IF проверки прошли успешно
$query = "INSERT INTO users (`user`, `password`) VALUES ('$login', '$pass')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // Проверяем записалось ли в БД

if ($result==true) {
    echo "<br>Информация в базу добавлена успешно.";
} else echo mysqli_error($link);
//Выполнить если все IF проверки прошли успешно
```

Comment: добавьте переменную флаг в блок всех проверок, и если условние в проверке не пройдено, присваивайте ей например `false` и в конце добавьте проверку этого флага и если он не `false` тогда выполняйте код.

Comment: `$login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])` функция здесь лишняя. Пропускать текст через `htmlspecialchars()` следует лишь при выводе его в бразуер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос ужас, вы этот код сами хоть писали? Тут очень мноого недочетов в плане мускула и html. + У вас текст ошибки слипнется при выводе:)

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    if($_GET['page'] == 'post') {
        // Приводим символы к хтмль и переводим в нижний регистр
        $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); //WHAT?
        $login = strtolower($login);
        $pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']); //WHAT??

        $ok = true;

        if (empty($login)) {
            $ok = false;
            echo 'Вы не заполнили поле логин';
        }
        if (strlen($login) > 33) {
            $ok = false;
            echo 'Логин длинее 32 символов, не допустим';
        }
        if (empty($pass)) {
            $ok = false;
            echo 'Поле пароль не может быть пустым';
        }
        if (strlen($pass) > 65) {
            $ok = false;
            echo 'Пароль должен содержать не более 64 символов';
        }
        if (strlen($pass) < 5) {
            $ok = false;
            echo 'Пароль должен содержать более 5 символов';
        }

        if($ok){
            //Выполнить если все IF проверки прошли успешно
            $query = 'INSERT INTO users (`user`, `password`) VALUES ('.$login.', '.$pass.');';
             //Вы слыхали о SQL ИНЬЕКЦИЯХ? 

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // Проверяем записалось ли в БД

            //Чтоза странность:)
            if ($result==true) {
                echo '<br></br>Информация в базу добавлена успешно.';
            } else echo mysqli_error($link);
            //Выполнить если все IF проверки прошли успешно

        }
    }
}
//УЧИТЕСЬ PHP
//ПОТОМ ДЕЛАЙТЕ РЕГИСТРАЦИИ
//
//
```

Comment: Конечно сам) Я ж говорю, что учусь)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($_GET['page']=="post") {
  $login = strtolower($_POST['name']);
  $pass  = $_POST['password'];

  $err = [];
  if(empty($login)){
    $err[] = "Вы не заполнили поле логин";
  }elseif(strlen($login) > 32){
    $err[] = "Логин длинее 32 символов, не допустим";
  }
  if(empty($pass)){
    $err[] = "Поле пароль не может быть пустым";
  }elseif(strlen($pass) > 64){
    $err[] = "Пароль должен содержать не более 64 символов";
  }elseif(strlen($pass) < 6){
    $err[] = "Пароль должен содержать более 5 символов";
  }

  if(!empty($err)){
    # здесь вывод ошибок
    return;
  }

  # здесь код, если нет ошибок
}
```

Comment: И следите за 32/33, 64/65 и т.д.

Comment: Если пароль будет равен 32 символам, проверка > 32 будет корректна в этом случае?

Comment: `if (strlen($login) > 33) {echo "Логин длинее 32 символов, не допустим";}`
в вашем варианте 33 символа - допустимый логин. а в тексте пишете "больше 32 нельзя".
Вчитайтесь в свои же слова. "больше 32 недопустимо" -- это 30,31,32 )